# Can't view (sub)category page

Tags: php, category

Neither my categories and subcategories can be seen.
It has the right link (http://zoio-magento.jelastic.websolute.net.br/index.php/catalog/category/view/id/4/) but when I click on it I get "There was no 404 CMS page configured or found." (no-route ?) message...

Products can be seen thought (http://zoio-magento.jelastic.websolute.net.br/index.php/sample-product.html).

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Make sure your categories are children of a root category, and that root category is set as root for the websites (system->manage stores)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments....
For a category to be accessible in the frontend, it needs to be a child of a root category, and that root category must be set a root for the current website. (System->Store management)